# How pass through an event in a ko.bindingHandler for TinyMce

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, tinymce

how can I call a function in the viewModel from within a ko.binding?

I want clicking on an editorable area to also show the selected text in a select-box.

I have also run into some other problems:

1. Full-text doesn´t show at until user has chosen from "select".
2. Editing the text in the full-text inline editor cause the outline editor to collapse.
3. Editing the header cause the observable to include all HTML-code for edited header.
4. In the binding: "tinymceInstance.remove()" returns an error message. Commenting it out however causes the desired highlighting function, but inline editor cannot be accessed.
5. Highlighting does not occur as wanted.

Here´s the html:

```
<select size="2" style="width: 170px;" data-bind="options: Textbatches, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', optionsText: 'TextbatchTitle', value: SelectedText, click: $root.showIt2Me"></select> 

<div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Textbatches:<img id="btnMetatoggle" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4-diag" style="display: inline-block" /></legend>
    <div id="details" class="textbatchdetails" data-bind="with: SelectedText">
        <div class="editor" data-bind="tinymce: TextbatchText, tinymceOptions: { selector: 'div.editor', inline: false }"></div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="full-text">
   <fieldset>
    <legend >Full text:</legend>
    <div>                    
    <!-- ko with: $root.SelectedText -->             
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.Textbatches() -->
        <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Text' + TextbatchId}, event:{ click: $root.clickedThis }, css: { 'inverted-text': TextbatchId === $root.SelectedText().TextbatchId}">
           <h2 class="editableArea" data-bind="tinymce: TextbatchTitle, tinymceOptions: { selector: 'h2.editableArea', inline: true }"></h2>
           <div class="editableArea" data-bind="tinymce: TextbatchText, tinymceOptions: { selector: 'div.editableArea', inline: true }"></div>
       </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    </fieldset>
 </div>
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8581f1y/23/

Any help highly appreciated. 
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you have for your binding handlers are incorrect.  You're misusing one of the parameters which is likely causing issues down the line.  For both `init()` and `update()`, the parameters are:

1. `element`
2. `valueAccessor`
3. `allBindings`
4. `viewModel`
5. `bindingContext`

Since you ultimately want a reference to the view model, there's no need to use the binding context, you have a direct reference to the view model right in the fourth parameter.

```
function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ...
    viewModel.someFunction(someArgs); // call directly on the view model
}
```

As for your other issues, I don't know much about tiny mce but you're making some assumptions that are invalid.  There is no `id` on the elements so it will always be undefined in your handler.  The id gets assigned after tiny mce is initialized on the element.  But since you just need to access the reference to the instance, all you need use is the element itself, not the id.

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function (element) {
    var tinymceInstance = $(element).tinymce(); // get the instance
    if (tinymceInstance) {
        tinymceInstance.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx, Jeff! It looks solid in the fiddle. However, when introducing this solution to my dev environment (DNN7) it causes a NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED. Strangely it appears on every second time I enter an editor. Removing the tinymceInstance.remove();-line seems ok for a while until I get a "too much recursion" error (about the 10th time or so I click in an editor).